# Generically filtering Lists for .NET 4.5 and parameterless constructors

Tags: c#, .net

I have looked all over Stack Overflow and cannot find an answer to this issue.
I am trying to generically filter an IEnumerable object based on the generic criteria that is passed into it.

```
private IEnumerable<TListItem> FilterList<TListItem, TListCriteria>(TListCriteria criteria) where TListItem: new()
{
//Do Work
return new IEnumerable<TListItem>();
}
```

The issue is that I have a constructor and I am getting an error that the TListItem must be a non-abstract with public parameterless constructor.  How can I use a class with a parameter contstructor for this type of generic call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not `TListItem`, but `IEnumerable` is an interface and cannot be instantiated at all, so you can't return new `IEnumerable`.

Try:

```
return Enumerable.Empty<TListItem>();
```

Second, you've specified a constraint for your generic:

```
where TListItem : new()
```

This exactly means `TListItem` must be a type with a parameterless constructor. So you might want to remove that constraint, if not needed.

Comment: You may want to add that if the goal is to filter an `IEnumerable<T>` and return that then you'd need to return something that implements it (like `List<T>`).

Comment: Not nessecarily. return someEnumerableAsInput.Where(p => p.SomeCondition); will return an IEnumerable of the same type, but not nessecarily a List

Comment: I didn't say it *had* to be a list, but it has to be *something* that implements `IEnumerable<T>`.  `List<T>` is an option, as is some LINQ query.  Returning an empty enumerable is probably not that useful if the goal is to filter something.

Comment: Sure, but OP's code tries to return a "new IEnumerable" as well, so I showed how to create an empty enumerable correctly. Anyway... I think his question rather relates to the second part of my answer, the new() constraint

Comment: I was able to take the new() out and use the IEnumerable<TListItem> as a parameter.  so I have the following:

    private IEnumerable<TListItem> FilterModelList<TListItem, TListCriteria>(IEnumerable<TListItem> modellist, TListCriteria criteria)
    {
       //do work....
        return modelList.Where(compiledlambdaexpression);
    }

Thanks for the help.